# Qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com integração contínua sem usar Docker?

Tags: php, svn, e-commerce, integração-contínua

Tenho uma aplicação de e-commerce em php que possui mais de 30k arquivos.

Estou implantando o processo de integração contínua com **Jenkins** + **SVN** + **Testes automatizados** ( *build* e *deploy* ).

Porém a aplicação não está usando **Docker**. Portanto a cada commit, fiz um script que pega as atualizações e as envia para o servidor de homologação.

Não compensaria trabalhar com rsync devido à grande quantidade de arquivos que existem na aplicação ou será que daria?

Testei outra forma de se fazer isso, criando um pacote já com a última versão sincronizada durante o processo de *build*. Depois no *deploy*, o "container" seria reinstalado na aplicação. Porém desta forma, o processo de deploy seria mais lento do que simplesmente enviar as atualizações.

O problema principal seria quando seriam apagadas ou criadas pastas, já que não é feito *rsync*.

Comment: Docker e rsync são só mais algumas das várias maneiras de se fazer o deploy de uma aplicação. Você precisa se perguntar: No que a sua solução atual deixa a desejar? Vale a pena alterar o seu workflow atual?

Comment: Na situação atual não compensaria reconfigurar toda a aplicação para usá-lo, devido ao tempo que foi gasto otimizando e configurando o servidor para rodar com php7, apc-cache, etc, a menos que poupe tempo futuramente.
É que vendo a ferramenta que é o Docker e o que ele traz de recursos, não usá-lo pareceria retrocesso.

Comment: Tenho uma configuração somelhante, no meu caso só troco o svn pelo git. Aqui separamos códigos de arquivos (imagens, docs, audios e etc). O servidor web é um repo git. A cada build no jenkins apenas os arquivos de códigos são atualizados por git pull, demais arquivos existe um rsync.